# motion detection of object in particular direction

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am a beginner in computer vision. I am experimenting with a project of my own. I am attempting to develop a motion detection system that can identify motion moving from left to right within a designated camera area. However, the algorithm I have implemented is not accurately detect motion in the specified direction. I've heard about using optical flow to improve this, but I'm unsure about how to implement it for my specific purpose. Can you provide guidance on modifying my algorithm or incorporating optical flow or some other technique to achieve accurate left-to-right motion detection of objects?

```
def detect_motion_direction(prev_frame, current_frame):
    # Convert frames to grayscale
    gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(prev_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Use the Lucas-Kanade method to calculate optical flow
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(gray1, gray2, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

    # Calculate the overall flow in the x and y directions
    avg_flow_x = np.mean(flow[..., 0])
    avg_flow_y = np.mean(flow[..., 1])

    # Determine the motion direction based on the overall flow
    if avg_flow_x > 0 and abs(avg_flow_y) < 0.2 * abs(avg_flow_x):
        return "Left to Right"
    else:
        return "Other Direction"
```

```
  video_file = 'example.mp4'  
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)


    # Read the first frame for comparison
    ret, prev_frame = cap.read()

    
    while ret:
       ret, current_frame = cap.read()
       if not ret:
          print("End of video")
          break
          # Determine motion direction
          direction = detect_motion_direction(prev_frame, current_frame)
          # Print the detected motion direction
          print("Motion detected:", direction)
      
          if direction == "Left to Right": somtheing
```

here is sample video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRHiMZN_mIb6dPewhOHpEoqHfMgC6_4O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The indentation isn't correct on second script.

Comment: @toyotaSupra do not worry about the indentation if you have a suggestion or logic , please let me know

Comment: @Astro currently I worry that your problem is not reproducible, please include the video in your question

Comment: @TinoD added video sample link